Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem implies Nested Set theorem.
I am trying to proof implication from Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem which states every bounded sequence has a sub sequence which converges to a real number, to Nested Set Theorem which state for a counted sequence of nested closed bounded non empty sets $\{I_n\}, I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 ...$ there infinite intersection is non empty $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i \neq \emptyset$
I want my proof to be verified for any incorrect steps.
Proof:
Let $\{I_n\}$ be countable sequence of nested closed bounded non empty sets and $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence following $c_i \in I_i$ where $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and I have defined  $s_j:=\{c^j_n\}$, for compactly representing one such sequence.

Lemma 1: for a set of increasing converging sequences $\{b^j\},\ b_1^j \leq b_2^j \leq b_3^j ...,\ \inf_j\lim_n b^j_n = \lim_n\inf_jb^j_n $
proof:
let $l_1 := \inf_j\lim_n b^j_n$ and $l_2 := \lim_n\inf_jb^j_n$
we will prove by contradiction, assume $l_1 -l_2 \neq 0$
its can be shown easily that there exist some $z$ for which $\lim_n b^z_n = l_1$, [I have not provided proof of this as it is straight forward proof by contradiction].
for each $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ there exist an $N_1$ and $N_2$ satisfying for all $n_1, n_2$ where $n_1 \geq N_1, n_2\geq N_2$
$|l_1 - b^z_{n_1}| \lt \epsilon_1$ and $|l_2 - \inf_j b^j_{n_2}| \lt \epsilon_2$
we prove for case $l_1 < l_2$ similar proof is for $l_1 > l_2$.
let $l_1 < x < c < y < l_2$ where $x:=\frac{c-l_1}{2}, y:=\frac{l_2-c}{2}$
now if $\epsilon_1 = x - l_1 > 0, \epsilon_2 = l_2 - y > 0$
then
$|l_1 - b^z_{n_1}| \lt x - l_1$, $|l_2 - \inf_j b^j_{n_2}| \lt l_2 - y$
$l_1 - (x - l_1) < b^z_{n_1} < l_1 + (x - l_1), l_2 - (l_2 - y) < \inf_j b^j_{n_2} < l_2 + (l_2 - y)$
$2l_1 -x \lt b^z_{n_1} \lt x, y \lt \inf_j b^j_{n_2} \lt 2l_2 -y $
$b^z_{n_1} < \inf_j b^j_{n_2}$ for all $n_1, n_2$ where $n_1 \geq N_1, n_2\geq N_2$ is a contradiction implying $l_1 = l_2$

we prove every possible cluster point from every possible subsequence of $s_j$ are between $\inf_j\lim\inf s_j$ and $\sup_j\lim\sup s_j$, and then proof $\inf_j\lim\inf s_j = \sup\{a_n\}$ , $\sup_j\lim\sup s_j = \inf\{b_n\}$, existence of such cluster points imply $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i \neq \emptyset$ in other words proves Nested Set Theorem.
Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem imply every bounded sequence has a converging subsequence as $s_j$ is bounded its cluster points are real numbers and every cluster point of a sequence $s_j$ is between $\lim\inf s_j$ and $\lim\sup s_j$[This is a theorem and can be verified from here https://plbailey79.github.io/portal/harc/z05f/t308x05.pdf] which also implies every cluster point of every sequence $s_j$ is between $\inf_j\lim\inf s_j$ and $\sup_j\lim\sup s_j$
Now proving $\inf_j\lim\inf s_j = \sup\{a_n\}$ , $\sup_j\lim\sup s_j = \inf\{b_n\}$
$\inf_j\lim\inf s_j = \inf_j\lim_n\inf_k\{c^j_k|k\geq n\} $
$=\lim_n\inf_j\inf_k\{c^j_k|k\geq n\}$, using lemma 1 as $\{\inf_k\{c^j_k|k\geq n\}\}$ is a increasing sequence
$=\lim_n\inf_k\inf_j\{c^j_k|k\geq n\}$ switching infimum
$=\lim_n\inf_k\{a_k|k\geq n\}$ as $c_i \in I_i $ and $ \inf I_i = a_i$
$=\lim_n \{a_n\} $ as $\{a_k|k\geq n\}$ is a increasing sequence
$=\sup\{a_n\}$ as limit of increasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ is its supremum
similarly $\sup_j\lim\sup s_j = \inf\{b_n\}$
this shows every cluster point of every possible sequence $s_j$ is present in every interval $I_i$ implying $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i \neq \emptyset$
Edit: As @SBK pointed out I should not have consider every such sequence $s_j$ and should have proved for cluster points for only one sequence $\{c_n\}$, meaning proving all cluster points from one sequence $\{c_n\}$ are between $\lim\sup\{a_n\}$ and $\lim\inf\{b_n\}$, such that the range of cluster point which is from $\lim\inf\{c_n\}$ to $\lim\sup\{c_n\}$ lie between $\lim\sup\{a_n\}$ and $\lim\inf\{b_n\}$ meaning I should have only proved for one sequence $\{c_n\}$, $\lim\sup\{a_n\} \leq \lim\inf\{c_n\}$ and $\lim\sup\{c_n\} \leq \lim\inf\{b_n\}$ holds to imply $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i \neq \emptyset$.
or just proving limit of converging sub-sequence of $\{c_n\}$ is present in all intervals, acquiring such a sub-sequence can be done by constructing a monotone increasing sub-sequence from original sequence $\{c_n\}$.
But as I have proved a general case stating every cluster point of every sequence $\{s_j\}$ is present in every interval $\{I_i\}$, I still want my proof to be verified.

actually my this line
$\lim_n\inf_jc^j_n$ as ${\inf_k{c^j_k|k\geq n}}$ is a increasing sequence might be incorrect, I am checking

corrected the transition to removing $\inf$

Are the sets supposed to be bounded? And I don’t understand what $s_n^j$ is supposed to be? You only need to pick the $c_n$ usually ( ie I dont know why you need a whole sequence for each $n$, if that’s what you’re doing)

$s_j$ represent $j$ sequence, $c^j_k$ represent $j$ sequence's $kth$ element, I have defined $s_j := {c^j_n}$, every sequence $s_j$ is bounded as all its elements $c^j_i \in I_i$ and $I_i$ is bounded. I forgot to mention bounded as I was using the same $I_i$ as from Nester Set Theorem.

I don’t think the proof needs a sequence of sequences. Try just taking one sequence ($c_n \in I_n$) and applying Bolzano—Weierstrass.

@SBK yeah that can also work, then I have to show $\lim\inf{c_n} \geq \sup{a_n}$ and $\lim\sup{c_n} \leq \inf{b_n}$

OK. I probably can’t get into much more of an extended conversation but I’m not sure why you are working with liminfs and limsups at all. I think for some reason you are trying to prove a stronger result. You only need one point in the intersection. That point will be a subsequential limit obtained via Bolzano—Weierstraas.

@SBK yeah I think your approach is straight forward to just proof limit of subsequence of sequence ${c_n}$ is present in all intervals, but I proved something more general and want it to be verified.

I have also corrected my lemma, it should be set of sequence not sequence of sequence, as the no of sequences can also be uncountable which they are.
